# Tag merge/synonym request: [memories-of-murders] » [memories-of-murder]

Tags: discussion, tags

There is currently a question with the tag, [memories-of-murders](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murders): [Who is the serial killer in Memories of Murders?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15211/who-is-the-serial-killer-in-memories-of-murders)

According to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0353969/reference) and [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/10003273_memories_of_murder), the English title of this movie is *Memories of Murder* (singular 'murder'). So the tag should be [memories-of-murder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murder).

Since [memories-of-murders](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murders) already has tag wiki info. I can't just edit the question's tag to [memories-of-murder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murder), as that info will not copy to the new tag. This is a request to merge or create a synonym of [memories-of-murders](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murders) » [memories-of-murder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murder).

EDIT: After posting this meta question, I've tried to post a question with the correct tag, [memories-of-murder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murder): [What is the significance of the dialogue,"Have some meat before you speak" between Inspectors Park and Suh?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102086/what-is-the-significance-of-the-dialogue-have-some-meat-before-you-speak-betwe)

However, I can't submit the question with that tag and got this error message:

> The tag [memories-of-murder] is too similar to [memories-of-murders]. If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have updated these two questions with [memories-of-murder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-of-murder). If plural one doesn't get used, it will die automatically.